# Magento 2 + custom eav field value store in array

Tags: magento2, collection, custom, filter

I have a custom eav structure and there is store_id save in array format in the database field.

I need to filer collection with addFieldToFilter with store_id.

```
$collection = $this->xyzCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', ['in' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()]);
```

Datastore in the database below format

```
["1","2","8","3","4","5"]
```

this filter is not working, anyone has an idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> **Reference Link :-** https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/

**Try This :**

```
$storeId[] = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
addAttributeToFilter('store_id', array('in' => array($storeId)));
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: please explain briefly what type of data you want and which format of data

Comment: Its quite clear, i need to match value of field, which field value store in array format in database.

Comment: you mean data store in array format ?

Comment: please attach example of your data format

Comment: question updated

Comment: check my updated answer you can create array of storid in check in condition

Comment: I have checked, maybe that's not working, I will accept your if that working or is there any mistake in custom eav, because that's is the right way but not working for me.

Comment: add value manually and check like array(1,2) pass the store id and check

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check that **store_id** field create in your custom table or not. If yes, then make sure that you extend `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection` class in your collection file.

For more reference : [click here](https://www.rohanhapani.com/create-eav-module-in-magento-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code regarding my friend RK

```
     $storeIds = array();
     $storeIds[] = 1; //store id
     $collection = $this->xyzCollectionFactory->create();
     $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', ['in' => (array)$storeIds]);

     Or

     $storeId = 1;
     $collection->getSelect()->where('main_table.store_id in (?)', [0, $storeId]);
```